# Applying padding to <input type="file" not working in Mozilla 12.0

Tags: html, css, padding

This is bugging me ... I have a simple HTML page that has a file typed input HTML object - see the line of code below:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="file" id="file" name="file" class="textbox" size="75" /></td></td>
</table>
```

In my CSS file I have:

```
input.textbox{padding:10px;font-size:14px}
```

The padding works fine in IE9 but does not appear to work in Mozilla.  Are there any considerations that I need to take into account with Mozilla?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set padding on the enclosing `td` element instead. File input widgets are implemented in special and varying ways in browsers, and they may be partly immune to CSS.

Comment: This is all true, but I'm pretty sure the OP wanted his padding inside the input box, not outside of it.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've seen is here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html. Style for file inputs are notoriously inconsistent across browsers, so it requires a bit of hack-work on the HTML.